# Change FCM sender ID

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugin-fcm

I had setup push notification in my App using the following command:

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="1234567890"
```

Which added the below code to my `package.json`

```
"phonegap-plugin-push": {
            "SENDER_ID": "1234567890"
        }
```

Now the issue is I have to change this sender ID to something else and I want to know how to do this, also I have the below code in my project to set up the `options` for push notification.

```
const options: PushOptions = {
  android: {
      senderID: '218580369028'
  },
  ios: {
      alert: 'true',
      badge: true,
      sound: 'false'
  },
  windows: {},
  browser: {
      pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
  }
 };
```

Is this as simple as just replacing the sender ID with what I want in `package.json` and in the above code. Or do I have to do something else for this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just install plugin again.

Comment: @PareshGami : Thanks, but is that the only way ?